# What distribution is this?

Tags: calculus, functions, probability-distributions

[image: Top: Uniform, Bottom: ?? Distribution. Ignore the random spikes those are just binning errors.]

Top: Uniform, Bottom: ?? Distribution. Ignore the random spikes - those are just binning errors.

---

Looking for a distribution that is on $[0,1]$ and is equal to $0$ at $1$ and some positive constant at $0$. The distribution starts off flat (horizontal?) and then tapers off to zero.

Before I just succumb to making it up myself with some arbitrary function, I wanted to check if such a distribution or similar already exists in common mathematical literature.

EDIT: I played around with the data and got clean CDFs,

[image: CDFs]

Comment: What was the arbitrary function?

Comment: Its possible its a mixed distribution

Comment: I added an image of the CDF if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This would be Fermi-Dirac distribution: 
\begin{equation}
f(\epsilon)=\frac{1}{e^{(\epsilon-u)/T}+1}
\end{equation}

Theory in short:

imagine we have levels $\epsilon_i$. Each level $\epsilon_i$ has $g_i$ sublevels and can be occupied with $n_i<g_i$ indistinguishable particles such that no more than one particle resides on one sublevel. We are given total number of particles $N=\sum_i n_i$ and total energy $E=\sum_i n_i \epsilon_i$. Average occupation of each level $\epsilon_i$ is given by $\bar{n}(\epsilon_i) = \frac{\bar{n}_i}{g_i}$. Occupation that corresponds to maximal number of ways to populate levels $\epsilon_i$ given constraints on $N$, $E$, is Fermi-Dirac distribution $f(\epsilon)$. In the formula $u$ and $T$ corresponds to $N$ and $E$ respectively.

[image: fdplot]

see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it's a good answer - but unfortunately not the right one! Turns out it was a completely different distribution stemming from a Beta-like distribution!

The Fermi-Dirac distribution that you provided does not EQUAL zero at 1.0, and the over all area under the curve between 0 and 1 is not 1 either, so it's not the distribution I had.

Thanks for the effort though! I still learned from your post :)